# R: variable lengths differ (found for"..") in glm function

Tags: r, variables, glm

```
 multiH<- glm(H ~sex+ region+ age+ incm+ edu+ occp + marri_1 + BD1_11+ BS3_1 +HE_BMI ,family=binomial(), na.action="na.exclude",data=hn1)
# sex with 1,2/ region for 1~10/ age for 30~99/ incm for 1~4/ occp for 1~3/ marri_1 for 1,2/  BD1_11 for 1,2/ BS3_1  for 1,2/ HE_BMI for 0~99
```

There is no NAs in my data.

Also did use the factor code for some variables.

I do not know the way to solve this error problem.

Which is

```
#variable lengths differ for "...."
```

Maybe the data frame should be the same, but is not..?

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = H ~ sex + region + age + incm +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'sex')

> str(hn1)
'data.frame':   27887 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ sex.age.incm.edu.occp.marri_1.BD1_11.BS3_1.H.Var: Factor w/ 19847 levels     "1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",..: 5222 13979 585 10962 13430 2938 12857 6137 15667 66 ...
```

This is the error sign I get...

```
 >hn1<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\hayon14\\Desktop\\HN.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep="\t"
> H<-factor(hn1$H)
> region<-factor(hn1$region)
> sex<-factor(hn1$sex)
> age<-factor(hn1$age)
> incm<-factor(hn1$incm)
> edu<-factor(hn1$edu)
> occp<-factor(hn1$occp)
> marri_1<-factor(hn1$marri_1)
> BD1_11<-factor(hn1$BD1_11)
> BS3_1<-factor(hn1$BS3_1)
> HE_BMI<-factor(hn1$HE_BMI)
> multiH<- glm(H ~sex+ region+ age+ incm+ edu+ occp + marri_1 + BD1_11+     BS3_1 +HE_BMI ,family=binomial(), na.action="na.exclude",data=hn1)
```

This is my full code.

Comment: To help troubleshoot can you post the full error message and edit your question with `str(hn1)`. Thanks

Comment: I have posted the str(hn1)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway..

Comment: okay, thank you. The structure is clear  - you have only one variable. Therefore, you have not managed to read in the data correctly. You are reading it in with read,csv, which assumes it is comma separated, but then you define the separator as tab separated. So just be sure what type of file you have. If you have read it in correctly, you will see a dataframe with more than one column.

Comment: It is always useful to check `str(hn1)`, `head(hn1)`, `tail(hn1)`,  and `summary(hn1)` after reading in data as checks.

Comment: I will try it again and let you know if there is any errors, thanks again.